# Javascript: what is "- 0" doing?

Tags: javascript

This is purely an educational question.

I'm working on a new version of a web app that the company I'm working for had made earlier. when re-writing the math, I came across this:

```
document.getElementById("estResidual").value-0;
```

Thinking there was no purpose for the "-0", I removed it. But when I tried the calculations, the numbers were waaayyyyyy off. Then I tried re-adding the "-0", and voila! everything worked nicely.

**The Question:**
What did the "-0" do to change the value?

Comment: Note - when you use `+ 0` it might still look like a concatenation. There is no confusion with the minus.

Comment: @Floris - just re-read your comment and realized that too... so I deleted mine. :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's an (ab)use of JavaScript's soft typing behavior. In this case, it will convert a string to a float:

```
> "13"
"13"
> "13"-0
13
> "1.01"-0
1.01
```

Unary `+` will do the same:

```
> +"13"
13
> +"9.9"
9.9
```

Note that using `+` will instead convert the integer `0` into a string and concatenate it:

```
> "13"+0
"130"
```

This is all standardized. For explicit details on how these operators should behave, you can always check the ECMAScript Language Specification (e.g. [addition](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.6.1), [subtraction](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.6.2). [unary plus](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.6)).

Comment: Why "abuse"? Certainly learning different ways to use a language is a beneficial thing, no? Or is this a practice that's best avoided due to the ease with which problems could occur with sloppy coding?

Comment: @DanTheGameMan: I personally don't like it because it's not obvious at all what the intent is. After all, you had to ask on stackoverflow what it does =). And then seeing that `-0` works, you might expect `+0` to work the same way, given the properties of arithmetic, but that gives you a totally different result! I'd recommend using `parseInt()` or `parseFloat()`

Comment: parseFloat seems to work nicely, and it is indeed **much** clearer on what's happening

Answer (score 1):

The JS engine re-casts on the fly to try and make statements work. So JS will cast "23" to an integer `23` when you try to perform math on it, and likewise it will convert integer `23` to string "23" if you do something like:

```
var a = 23;
console.log(23 + "asdf");
//outputs "23asdf"
```

Comment: It's not really a static typing issue. A statically typed language could have this exact behavior, wherein the type of the expression `<string> - <integer>` would be `<integer>`.

Answer (score 1):

That forces the type of object to become a number rather than a string.

Comment: well Claudiu's answer is way better than mine